# How to give an variable as an input in filter's contain option in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find an exact word from a sentence by excel VBA with below code.

```js
Dim col As Range, cell1 As Range, a As String, i As Integer
Set col = Range("KW[KW1]")
Dim target, cell As Range
Sheets("Data").Select
Set target = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
Dim term, tag As String
    For Each cell1 In col
    a = cell1.Value
    term = a
    tag = a

        For Each cell In target
            
            
            If InStr(1, cell, term, 1) Then
            
                For i = 1 To 50
                    If cell.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, i).Value = tag
                    GoTo Step1
                    End If
                Next i

        End If
Step1:
        Next cell
    Next cell1
          
End Sub
```

But its giving result for "wood" from "Rosewood" which is wrong. How to find only exact word "wood"

Comment: You need to include spaces in your `InStr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do exact word searches is to surround the search text and the word you're looking for with spaces.  Using your code it would like this:

```
If InStr(1, " " & cell & " ", " " & term & " ", 1) Then
```

That way it won't find "wood" within "Rosewood"